# Testing iOS app with just an iPad

Tags: ios, testing

Is it possible to extensively test an iOS app with just an iPad. In particular,

1) Can I easily switch between iOS4 and iOS5 on the iPad?

2) Can I run an iPhone or iPod touch simulator on the iPad?

Comment: Simulator on ipad?  are you sure you got the question right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't easily switch between different iOS versions on your iPad.
2. You can't run a iPhone or iPod Touch simulator on the iPad.

What you can do is testing your application in Xcode with the build-in simulator for iPad and iPhone.

Comment: One should not submit an app which wasn't tested on device.

Answer (score 3):

1) No.

2) No.

You could additionally buy an iPod touch and test on that too.